# Stripping formatting from text - Am I using an efficient jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, formatting

I'm making a comment box using a contenteditable div, but I want to remove formatting from text a user might copy/paste into it (also no <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> shortcuts allowed either). Only "approved" formatting ("tagged" names, URLs, etc).

Originally I went the regex route but was informed regex + html is not a good approach, so I then tried using jQuery/DOM manipulation and found a solution there as well.

I am worried though, that my jQuery selector used in `$nodesToReplace` is too long and possibly inefficient although it basically describes what I want returned. I'm just wondering if there was another more elegant/shorter/more efficient way to do this that I may have overlooked. Here's the code:

Two utility functions (for reference)

```
// Change an Element's type (change it's html tags) to "newType"
jQuery.fn.changeElemTypeTo = function(newType){
  // just make sure it's a plain element name
  newType.replace(/[<\/>]/ig,'');

  var newElemStr = '<' + newType + '>' + this.html() + '</' + newType + '>';
  console.log('*Nodes with tags replaced: ',newElemStr);
  return this.replaceWith(newElemStr);
};

// Remove/strip the html tags from an element
jQuery.fn.removeElemTags = function(){
  var tmp = this.replaceWith(this.html());
  console.log('*Node with tags Removed: ',this.html());
  return tmp;
};
```

main handler with super long selector in `$nodesToReplace`...

```
$('#input').on('paste', function() {
  var $inputDiv = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    var oldHTML = '', newHTML = '';
    // look through the commentbox for headings and other (mostly) block
    // elements
    var $nodesToReplace = $inputDiv.find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,address,article,aside,blockquote,div,p,pre,dd,dt');
    var $nodesToRemove = $inputDiv.find('*').not($nodesToReplace);

    $nodesToRemove.each(function(){
      console.log('Nodes with tags to remove: ',$(this).outerHtml());
      $(this).removeElemTags();
    });

    $nodesToReplace.each(function(){
      console.log('Nodes with tags to replace: ',$(this).outerHtml());
      $(this).changeElemTypeTo('p');
    });
  }, 10);
});
```

I also have a demo on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/adazel/10/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue in the past, and decided to simply use a disposable DOM element to convert the HTML to plaintext:

```
var message = "..."; // Contains HTML markup
var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
tmp.innerHTML = message;
var message = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
// message now contains plaintext, and tmp can be disposed of
```

With this approach, we still needed to allow the user to enter a single tag. For this, we simply implemented a microformat where the user enters "placeholders" with bracket symbols:

> Hello [[person]], having a good day?

Since this is just plain text, it will not be removed by the above conversion process, and can simply be replaced with the appropriate HTML tags:

```
message.replace('/\[\[person\]\]/g', '<strong>some name</strong>');
```

Comment: wow thanks, can't believe I didn't know about the `textContent` property before